# Nginx shared memory with limit_req_zone

Tags: nginx, load-balancing, reverse-proxy

So actually I'm using nginx to reverse proxy (and load balancing) some API backend servers with nginx and I'm using the directive `limit_req_zone` to limit max requests per IP and URI. No problem with that.

Eventually we might need to scale out and add a couple more of nginx instances. Every nginx instance uses a "shared memory zone" to temporary save (in a cache, I guess) every request so it can properly check if the request passes or not accordingly with the `limit_req_zone` mentioned above. That being said, how does nginx handles it if multiple nginx are running at same time?

For example:

`limit_req_zone $binary_remote_addr zone=one:10m rate=1r/s;`

This tells nginx to only allow 1 request per second coming from the same IP address, but what about if the second request (within the same second) comes to another nginx instance? As I understand, it will pass because they not share the shared memory where it stores the cache, I guess.

I've been trying to research a bit about it but could't find anything. Any help would be appreciate.

Answer (score 0):

If by multiple nginx you mean multiple master processes, I'm not completely sure what the result is. To have multiple master processes running, they would need to have different configs / different ports to bind.

For worker processes with a single master instance, the shared memory is precisely that, shared, and all of the workers will limit the requests together. The code documentation says:

> shared_memory — List of shared memory zones, each added by calling the ngx_shared_memory_add() function. Shared zones are mapped to the same address range in all nginx processes and are used to share common data, for example the HTTP cache in-memory tree.

http://nginx.org/en/docs/dev/development_guide.html#cycle

In addition, there's a blog entry about limit_req stating the following:

> Zone – Defines the shared memory zone used to store the state of each IP address and how often it has accessed a request‑limited URL. Keeping the information in shared memory means it can be shared among the NGINX worker processes. The definition has two parts: the zone name identified by the zone= keyword, and the size following the colon. State information for about 16,000 IP addresses takes 1 megabyte, so our zone can store about 160,000 addresses.

Taken from https://www.nginx.com/blog/rate-limiting-nginx/